# how to randomly generate a unqiue number from an array in java

Tags: java, blackberry

i want to generate numbers frm an array randomly,& every number should be unique as well,i am giving the piece of code.Kindly help me out,& plz dnt suggest for arraylist,bcoz i am building for blackberry app,& blackberry api doesnt support arraylist or collection or hashset,so kindly suggest me with array only in dis piece of code.

```
 Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator

    //--- Initialize the array 
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        quesNum[i] = i;
    }
```

//--- Shuffle by exchanging each element randomly

```
   for (int i=0; i< 20; i++) {
        int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(20);

        int temp = quesNum[i];

        quesNum[i] = quesNum[randomPosition];

        quesNum[randomPosition] = temp;


    }
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what this code is doing that you do not want or what you want that this code does not?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is nearly okay as it is, but you should use a modified [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) instead:

```
for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
    // Partition the array into "shuffled" at the start
    // and "unshuffled" at the end. Select a random
    // unshuffled one, and swap it with the one at the
    // border of shuffled/unshuffled
    int randomPosition = i + rgen.nextInt(20 - i);
    int temp = quesNum[i];
    quesNum[i] = quesNum[randomPosition];
    quesNum[randomPosition] = temp;
}
```

It wasn't really clear from your question what you were asking for - validation that you were thinking along the right lines? If this answer doesn't help you, please clarify the question (ideally without text-speak abbreviations).